# Get timeZone from Timestemp in ireport

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am working with ireport 5.5.0 and and PostgreSQL, I am using this query to get date informations

```
SELECT move.date as date FROM move
```

the result is `2017-02-13 09:12:00` but i need to get time from this informations like this `09:12:00`

To get this informations i'am using this query

```
EXTRACT('HOUR' FROM move.date) || ':' || EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM move.date) as date
```

and the result is `9:12`

Is there a query to get time from TimeStamp ?!?

Comment: Are you running on an Oracle database?

Comment: Uh...yeah, don't you think that's relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TO_CHAR()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(move.date, 'HH12:MI:SS')
FROM move
```

Note that if you want 24 hour time, you can use `TO_CHAR(move.date, 'HH24:MI:SS')` instead.

As to whether you choose 24 hour or 12 hour time, it is up to whoever is the target of your report.  If you were presenting to consumers in the US, you would almost certainly be using 12 hour time.  For some Europeans countries, or possibly a military audience, you would be using 24 hour time.

Comment: Worked fine thank you but can you please give me more informations about what is the difference between `'HH24:MI:SS'` and `'HH12:MI:SS'`

Comment: @YagamiLight 12 hour time is what many people normally use everyday, e.g. there is an `11am` and an `11pm`, and they are 12 hours apart.  24 hour time, often referred to as military time, labels each hour from 1 to 24.  As to which one you choose, it is up the needs of your report.